# Frame Tkinter Python não fica do lado de outro frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

Bom, estou com um problema ao montar minha interface gráfica simples de um programa. Estou fazendo ela com tkinter usando python 3 e um frame simplesmente não fica do lado do outro! Já tentei colocar side=LEFT nos 2, e mais uma diversidade de coisas. O problema é simples, porém não consigo enxergar onde está o erro.

O código é o seguinte:

```
from tkinter import *
import _thread
import threading


def atualizarInterface(atoa):
    while True:
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.update()


def iniciarThreadAtualizar():
    _thread.start_new_thread(atualizarInterface, tuple([1]))


class InterfaceGrafica:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.corVerde = "color-" + 'green'
        self.corAzul = "color-" + 'blue'
        self.corCinza= "color-" + 'grey'

        self.fontePadrao = ("Arial", "12")
        self.fonteTitulos = ("Arial", "12", "bold")

        self.containerGeral = Frame(master)
        self.containerGeral.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.containerMenu = Frame(self.containerGeral, bg='#cbccc6', width=100)
        self.containerMenu.pack(side=LEFT, anchor='nw', fill=Y, expand=YES)

        self.containerCanvas = Frame(self.containerGeral, bg='black', width=100, height=100)
        self.containerCanvas.pack(side=LEFT, anchor='nw', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.containerBotoes = Frame(self.containerMenu, bg='#cbccc6')
        self.containerBotoes.pack(fill=X, anchor='nw')

        self.botaoTranslacao = Button(self.containerBotoes, text="Translação", bd=2, font=self.fonteTitulos)

        self.botaoRotacao = Button(self.containerBotoes, text="Rotação", bd=2, font=self.fonteTitulos)

        self.botaoEscala = Button(self.containerBotoes, text="Escala", bd=2, font=self.fonteTitulos)

        self.botaoReflexao = Button(self.containerBotoes, text="Reflexões", bd=2, font=self.fonteTitulos)

        self.botaoTranslacao.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES)
        self.botaoRotacao.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES)
        self.botaoEscala.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES)
        self.botaoReflexao.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES)

        self.containerAzul = Frame(self.containerMenu, bg='blue')
        self.containerAzul.pack(anchor='nw', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)


root = Tk()
root.title("Trabalho Computação Gráfica")
root.geometry("800x480")
interface = InterfaceGrafica(root)
root.after(100, iniciarThreadAtualizar)
root.mainloop()
```

Eu quero que esse containerCanvas fique bem ao lado e colado ao outro container que é o containerMenu. Vou mostrar como está saindo o resultado disso:

**OBS: O Container com botões e uma parte azul é o containerMenu, e o todo preto (que é o que quero que fique bem do lado), é o containerCanvas**

[image: Container preto (containerCanvas) não fica do lado do containerMenu]

Alguém poderia me dizer o que está causando isso? Vivo tendo problemas com essa organização de frames, não consigo colocar na tela o que realmente estou querendo.

O container preto tem que preencher todo o resto da tela também, coloquei ele com 100 de width e height só para testar.

Comment: retira o expand do containerMenu

Comment: Boa! Funcionou! Sabe explicar o porque?

Comment: ñ sei, só acho que um entra em conflito com o outro